# Values occurring the same number of times in $(1-5kx^3) \pmod{25}$

Tags: number-theory

> Is there an easy way to tell that $(1-5kx^3) \pmod{25}$ takes on the values $1,6,11,16,21$ the same number of times if $0 \leq k \leq 4$ and $1 \leq x \leq 4$?

We could always list all the elements mod $25$ to get $1,1,1,1,-, 21,11,16,6,-,16,21,6,11,-,11,6,21,16,-,6,16,11,21$ where "-" denotes a multiple of $25$, but the fact that there are exactly four of each doesn't seem like a coincidence. Is there a way of determining that they all must occur the same amount of times without listing?

Answer (score 1):

The problem boils down to showing that $x\mapsto x^3$ is a bijective map on $\mathbb{F}_5^*$, that is straightforward since it is an involutive map by Fermat's little theorem: $x^9\equiv x\pmod{5}$.

Comment: How do you know that $(1-5kx) \pmod{25}$ takes on the values $1,6,11,16,21$ the same number of times if $0 \leq k \leq 4$ and $1 \leq x \leq 4$?

Comment: @user19405892: the identity is an injective map on $\mathbb{F}_5^*$, too.

Comment: What does it being injective tell us?